# How to convert jQuery that grab YouTube title to function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery code which grabs YouTube titles.

```
$.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id={VIDEOID}&key={YOUR API KEY}&part=snippet&callback=?',function(data){
    if (typeof(data.items[0]) != "undefined") {
        console.log('video exists ' + data.items[0].snippet.title);
       } else {
        console.log('video not exists');
     }   
    });
```

I want to make it as a function so that I can pass YouTube id as a parameter.

Comment: So do it.  What's the question?

Comment: Sorry I don't know jquery :(

Comment: Making a function and string concatenation, or template literals, is not jQuery

Comment: jQuery and vanilla both share the same syntax for creating functions...

Comment: It's all javascript.  jQuery is just a javascript library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make it into a function, it's pretty easy to do:

```
function youtubeVideo(videoID, apiKey) {

   $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id='+videoID+'&key='+apiKey+'&part=snippet&callback=?',function(data){
    if (typeof(data.items[0]) != "undefined") {
        console.log('video exists ' + data.items[0].snippet.title);
       } else {
        console.log('video not exists');
     }   
    });

}
```

Note that we're passing in videoID and apiKey to the function. In order to call this, you'd simply:

```
youtubeVideo(video_id_here, api_key_here);
```